# Creating a customized wallpaper

Tags: customization, wallpaper

I have a small doubt about posting my question here. But still posting so that if wrong I might get the right site.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>This is a wallpaper I found on the ZEDGE (click to enlarge)</sup>

This is a wallpaper I found on the ZEDGE app and I liked it. Now I just want to create my own customized wallpaper like this(to be precise, just replacing the words or some logos in this wallpaper), such as I wanted to put my own words etc.

Can anyone help me by telling me how that can be done on Android (basically).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify that wallpaper, then you will need to find a photo editor and change whatever you want on it. For simply changing words on a picture, any photo editor will do, even one as simplistic as Microsoft Paint, as well as more complex options, like Photoshop and GIMP.

Although there are photo-editing apps available for Android, this isn't really an Android-specific question, since this process can be done on any platform, and therefore does not belong on this SE site. However, you probably needed an answer, and I chose to provide you one.

I hope this advice helps you do whatever you needed to do!